# How can I escape special characters when calling SharePoint Search Using REST

Tags: search, special-characters

I would like to perform a Sharepoint Search based on the keyword : "l'avion" using rest.
However, an error is returned because of the special character "'" contained in the keyword.
How can I fix this problem when using special characters and make it work properly ?

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 0):

Escape the character with "'"...

```
_api/search/query?querytext='l''avion'
```